# where does cisco switches store dynamically learned secure mac addresses?

Tags: cisco, port-security

we all know that if we use the command

```
show port-security address
```

we'll see the entire table of secure mac addresses. 
I need to know which file does IOS use to store these addresses (specifically the dynamic addresses) on?

Thanks,

Comment: Please help us understand what you would do with the answers.  You might find that you've made assumptions which are not true; however, if you tell us what you're trying to solve or implement, we can potentially be much more helpful than saying "Cisco IOS doesn't store mac-addresses in a file"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I believe that these secure addresses should be stored somewhere :) if it doesn't then how the "switchport port-security aging" works? Actually I need to know how many mac-addresses are used on a switch port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to know which file does IOS use to store these addresses (specifically the dynamic addresses) on?

I'm afraid that's not how Cisco IOS stores information.  Cisco's [CAM table](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/51718) is not stored in a file.

> [Seena Moshiri said](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13461/where-does-cisco-switches-store-dynamically-learned-secure-mac-addresses?noredirect=1#comment20722_13461): I believe that these secure addresses should be stored somewhere :) if it doesn't then how the "switchport port-security aging" works?

This works the same way that all other mac-address tables work in Cisco switches.  Typically the mac-addresses are stored in a [TCAM](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/60831/cam-vs-tcam), which is a kind of memory optimized for quick lookups.

If you want to see what is in the `port-security` mac-address table, these are some possible options:

- Use the [`CISCO-PORT-SECURITY-MIB`](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&step=2&mibName=CISCO-PORT-SECURITY-MIB). However, MIB queries are complicated.
- Use a script to capture from Cisco IOS CLI, and parse the values into whatever format you want